# php check license id with postback url

Tags: php, licensing, postback, file-get-contents

I'm working on a php installer for a web application / software.

The installer need a valid license ID to finish the installation (for example: "aDs34Nsi9sa").

To check if the license ID is valid i have a php script on my main domain that check my db and return 1 if the licenseID exist and is active or 0 otherwise. This file should be called like this:

```
https://www.domain.com/check.php?id=aDs34Nsi9sa
```

So i'm wondering if is correct to use file_get_contents() to check the license ID via PHP..

```
$check = file_get_contents("https://www.domain.com/check.php?id=$license_field");
if( $check == 1 ) {} // finish installation
else {} // print error msg
```

Is this way correct and secure?

Comment: Why would you use `file_get_contents` to check for the value of `id` ?? This does not make sense

Comment: @Simon_eQ i'm not sure about file_get_contents(), this is why i have post the question. what function should i use?

Comment: Just use `$_GET['id']`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you need to properly URL-encode data before injecting it into a URL. And it's up to your remote server to detect brute force attacks. Other than that:

- Your check assumes that [`allow_url_fopen` is enabled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) and PHP has [SSL support](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php). Make sure you explain that in the requisites and get ready for support enquiries and workaround coding.
- Data sent through SSL should remain private enough.
- And, well, it isn't particularly difficult to crack. Malicious users just need to impersonate the remote site.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you suggest me a better way or should I simple use the method above with an additional secret key and a brute-force protection?

Comment: Sorry, I've never worked on this kind of stuff. I suppose professional licence systems use cryptography but I couldn't tell you how.